# Gradle integration test produces java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, gradle, migration

I am migrating multi-module Gradle Java project from Gradle `4.10` to Gradle `6.3`.
Project structure looks like the following:

```
├── build.gradle
├── our-webapp
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       ├── integrationTest
│       └── test
└── cli-util
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
        ├── main
        ├── integrationTest
        └── test
```

`cli-util` has a dependency on webapp to use it's classes.
`build.gradle` looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output

        java.srcDir 'src/integrationTest/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/integrationTest/resources'
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':our-webapp')
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

And now what is interesting is that tests under `cli-util/src/intergrationTest` are working fine in Intellij IDEA but they are failing from terminal whenever there is an import of a class defined in `webapp` project. The error is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/web/SomeClass`.

I tried different approaches already, including the use of `java-library` plugin in `cli-util` project and importing `webapp` project like `api project(':our-webapp')` but it still fails.

Same issue in Gradle `5.6.x`.

Is there some special change I have take into account to make it work?

Comment: I don't think it resolves your problem, but `integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime` should be `integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly` as the `testRuntime` is a deprecated configuration that should not be used.

Comment: Hi @rand0m86 have you been able to fix this ?